# Missing separator in C/C++ eclipse gcc error

Tags: c++, eclipse

I am writing c++ program for weather report and I'm getting following error

```
/*
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
make: *** missing separator.  Stop. subdir.mk   /weather/Debug/src  line 21 C/C++ Problem

*/
```

Code works fine on visual studio but it doesn't work on ECLIPSE CDT (gcc compiler).

Here is image: (http://prntscr.com/5nnpap)

Here is code:

```
    /*
* aks.cpp
*
*  Created on: 31-Dec-2014
*      Author: student
*/

#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>

using namespace std;

class weather_report
{
public:

    int day, hightemp, lowtemp, amtrain, amtsnow;



    weather_report()
    {
        day = 99;
        hightemp = 999;
        lowtemp = -999;
        amtrain = 0;
        amtsnow = 0;
    }

    void display()
    {
        cout << "\n " << day;
        cout << "\t\t" << hightemp;
        cout << "\t" << lowtemp;
        cout << "\t" << amtrain;
        cout << "\t" << amtsnow;

    }

    void Accept()
    {
        cout << "\n enter day  ";
        cin >> day;
        cout << "\n enater hightemp  ";
        cin >> hightemp;
        cout << "\n enter lowtemp  ";
        cin >> lowtemp;
        cout << "\n enter rain  ";
        cin >> amtrain;
        cout << "\n enter snow  ";
        cin >> amtsnow;

    }

    void average(int i)
    {
        i++;
        int a;
        float avg;
        a = hightemp + lowtemp + amtrain + amtsnow;
        avg = (float)a / 4;
        cout<<endl<< "avg for day " << i << " = " << avg << endl;
    }

};

int main()
{
    int i, n;
    weather_report w[5];
    cout << "\n how many days:";
    cin >> n;
    cout << "\n enter data: "<<endl;
    for (i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        w[i].Accept();
    }

    cout <<endl<<endl<< "entered data are";
    for (i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        cout<<endl<< " " << endl << i + 1 << "day";
        w[i].display();
    }

    cout <<endl<< endl;
    for (i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        cout << endl<<"calculating avg ";
        w[i].average(i);

    }

    return 0;

}
```

Here is output on visual studio:-

```
/* output


 how many days:3

 enter data:

 enter day  1

 enater hightemp  45

 enter lowtemp  25

 enter rain  11

 enter snow  13

 enter day  2

 enater hightemp  34

 enter lowtemp  23

 enter rain  12

 enter snow  33

 enter day  3

 enater hightemp  54

 enter lowtemp  34

 enter rain  60

 enter snow  23


entered data are

1day
 1              45      25      11      13

2day
 2              34      23      12      33

3day
 3              54      34      60      23


calculating avg
avg for day 1 = 23.5

calculating avg
avg for day 2 = 25.5

calculating avg
avg for day 3 = 42.75

*/
calculating avg
avg for day 3 = 42.75

*/
```

But same code doesn't works on eclipse (gcc compiler)

Comment: _Missing separator_ is an error of `make` build tool, not of the source code. So the problem is inside `subdir.mk` as pointed out in error report. I'm not sure if the makefile is automatically generated by Eclipse or what but it's another kind of problem.

Comment: Use tab, not spaces in line 21

Comment: @ neiiic : line 21 is in file "subdir.mk" which is automatically generated. i can't change it.

Comment: Then configure correctly the thing generating `subdir.mk`

Comment: @ Basile Starynkevitch : how?

Comment: @Jack: its automatically generated by eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why its didn't work on eclipse(3.8) but works on visual studio.
But i updated eclipse to 4.4v and GCC to 4.9 , now same code working fine without giving error.